# Allow saving an existing entry in Laravel with FormRequest and unique

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-5.1

Still noob and learning Laravel, I am currently in the middle of a simple validation with FormRequest. What I am facing today is the edit of an existing entry.

I have written in my FormRequest that I want the `name` to be unique. It works perfectly but of course when I edit an existing entry, I cannot save it anymore, it already exists... of course it does since I am editing it.

I found the solution reading the documentation, but unfortunately, it does not work. Here's my code:

Routes:

```
Route::resource('editeurs', 'PublishersController');
```

Controller:

```
class PublishersController extends Controller
{
    /* Update an existing publisher */
    public function update($slug, PublisherRequest $request)
    {
        $publisher = Publisher::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();

        $input = $request->all();

        $publisher->name = $input['name'];
        $publisher->slug = my_slug($input['name']);

        $publisher->save();

        return redirect()->action('PublishersController@show', $publisher->slug);
    }
}
```

FormRequest:

```
class PublisherRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|unique:publishers,name,'.?????
        ];
    }
}
```

If needed, the view:

```
@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <h1 class="large-12 columns">Edition - {!! $publisher->name !!}</h1>

        {!! Form::model($publisher, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'action' => ['PublishersController@update', $publisher->slug]]) !!}
        <div class="large-12 columns">
            {!! Form::label('name', 'Nom de l\'éditeur') !!}
            {!! Form::text('name', null, ['placeholder' => 'Nom de l\'éditeur']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="large-12 columns">
            {!! Form::submit('Ajouter un éditeur', ['class' => 'button expand']) !!}
        </div>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
    </div>
@stop
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Your form request code looks fine so it should work. Are you getting redirected back to the form at `users/{id}/edit` when submitting, and there are errors in `session('errors')`?

Comment: Yes I am redirected to the form and it displays the error : `the name already exists`

Comment: I'm assuming you are 100% sure there are no other entries that have that name.

Comment: Try using `$this->id` (which is implemented by Laravel) instead of `$this->get('id')` (which is implemented by Symfony), maybe it will make a difference (alltough it should't).

Comment: Yep there's only one Test4 (that's my test entry), since in my database, I don't allow multiple names. I added `$this->id` but I still have the error message : `The name has already been taken.`

Comment: What's the output if you place `dd($this->id);` in your `rules()` method before the return statement? Is it the correct user `id` passed in the URL?

Comment: I get an answer too long for the comment. What's interesting could be: `+request: ParameterBag {#163 ▼
    #parameters: array:3 [▼
      "_method" => "PATCH"
      "_token" => "Dz16pXtfCS8Jw9CzjwzqPOSMWdWo200R9bGRQv9J"
      "name" => "Test4"
    ]
  }`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "I get an answer too long for the comment".

Comment: Stackoverflow does not let me paste all I get... I've edited my previous comment. Maybe you can specify what exactly you're expecting so I can paste it

Comment: Use [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/) and post the link.

Comment: http://hastebin.com/hopisuyeje.coffee

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

```
    class PublishersController extends Controller
        {
            /* Update an existing publisher */
            public function update($slug, PublisherRequest $request)
            {
                $publisher = Publisher::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();

                $this->validate($request, ['name' =>'required|unique:publishers,name,'.$publisher->id]);

                $publisher->name = $request->input('name');
                $publisher->slug = my_slug($publisher->name);

                $publisher->save();

                return redirect()->action('PublishersController@show', $publisher->slug);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to separate the validation from the controller. And I assume the FormRequest has been created to perform all kind of validations, including this one. The thing is, it's present in the official Laravel documentation...

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the solution. I needed to pass the slug of my current publisher.

```
public function rules()
{
    $publisher = Publisher::where('slug', $this->editeurs)->first();

    return [
        'name' => 'required|unique:publishers,name,'.$publisher->id
    ];
}
```

This works.